# MOD REWRITE Wordpress local VS. LIVE

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my problem is, that under MAMP the ROOT Directory is recognised different than LIVE an i have really no clue of MOD_REWRITE so i can't reuse some other examples

**Can i do some if condition so it will work both LIVE and LOCAL?**

This is LIVE

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is LOCAL

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project_directory_under_htdocs/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /project_directory_under_htdocs/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i think when you uploaded code on-live, it will automatically works for that. you just need to go to permalink section and click on save button without make any changes (As per my knowledge).

Comment: Yes you are right... Wordpress will save it right... But i need it with a solution for both..because of Version control .. Git.. i always have ti change it weather u am live or local